# How can I use activity class methods in a class that extends from GLScreen class?

Tags: java, android

I am extending my class from GLScreen class. But I need to call the Activity class methods such as getString and getPreferences. How can I call these methods? Because I can extend only from one class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a reference of your Activity to your class to able to call getPreferences()/getString(). You can do this via constructor/setter.

Something like this:

```
public YOURCLASS extends GLScreen {

     Activity mActivity;

     public YOURCLASS(Activity activity){
         mActivity = activity;
     }

     ...

     // call this in a method
     mActivity.getString(...);
}
```

In your Activity call it like this:

```
YOURCLASS foo = new YOURCLASS(this);
```

Comment: When I do I like this I get the exception "can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare'. I tried these ways:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare
It gives null pointer exception. Please help

Comment: @user3634684 Then ask a question with all your details! What you want to achieve and what code you already have.